# How to derive OLS estimator in matrix term

Tags: least-squares

In matrix term:
$$y=X\beta+\epsilon$$
Using OLS:
$$\hat{\beta}=(X'X)^{-1}X'y$$
Question: why cannot I do the following
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{\beta} &=(X'X)^{-1}X'y \\
&= X^{-1}X'^{-1}X'y\\
&=X^{-1}y
\end{align}
$$
The Assumption that X has no multicollinearity ensures $X'X$ invertible but not $X$?

Comment: Only square matrices are invertible, but $X$ is not square in general, so $X^{-1}$ may not even exist. On the other hand, $X^T X$ is always square.

Comment: Your derivation could for example work in the (not overly relevant) case where you have as many observations as predictors. Also, I assume you are confusing $\epsilon$ and $y$.

Comment: You *almost can* do that! (Assuming, as @ChristophHanck mentions that you meant $y$ instead of $\epsilon$). You just need to use the *generalized inverse*, i.e. it's true that $\hat{\beta} = \mathbf{X}^\dagger\mathbf{y}$ where $\dagger$ denotes generalized inversion; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse

Comment: @ChristophHanck, thanks for pointing it out. I edited it.